# Цепочка вызовов jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет.

```
<body>
    <div class="class0"> <a href="">link</a> </div>
    <div class="class0"></div>
    <div class="class0"></div>
</body>

<script>
    proto={};

    $ = function(selector){
        var tags = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        tags.__proto__ = proto;
        return tags;
    }

    proto.addClass = function(className){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            this[i].classList.add(className);
        }
        return this;
    }

    proto.html = function(){
        return this[0].innerHTML;
    }
</script>

console.log( $('div').addClass('class1').html() ); так работает
console.log( $('div').addClass('class1').html().addClass('class 2').html() ); а так нет.
```

Функция `html()`, с одной стороны, должна возвращать `this[0].innerHTML`, а с другой - `this`. Как это объединить, не знаю, как-то надо использовать `toString()` / `valueOf()`.

Comment: @olegall, какой вообще замысел у функции html()? Что она должна делать?

Comment: аналог метода html() в jQuery. Должна вывести чистый html 1-го дива

Comment: Согласно описанию, метод html(), как и свойство innerHTML, возвращают строку, представляющую собой HTML код внутри элемента. В общем, у меня он так и работает, никакого nodeList. Или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Скорее всего упускаешь. Надо добиться того, чтобы

    console.log( $('div').addClass('class1').html().addClass('class 2').html() );

выводило 2 раза  

    <a href="">link</a>